# How to open Emacs inside Bash

Tags: bash, emacs

I'm using [Ubuntu 11.10](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_%28Unix_shell%29) (Oneiric Ocelot). When I type the command "emacs" in the terminal, it opens Emacs as a separate window. How can I open it inside the terminal, like the [nano](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_nano) editor?

Comment: As always when I see a such question, I wonder why you would want to do that. With a graphical emacs you could use every fonts you want, nice colorscheme, use the image support, etc …

Comment: @Daimrod: sometimes a new window popping up harrasses the concentrated mind. Sometimes you want to do a quick one in an existing window and sometimes you want to reserve a whole room for your thing.

Comment: @Daimrod because sometimes you're editing files across two ssh hops on a slow link and the X version of emacs is too much for your connection.

Comment: Also, one might want to practice using Emacs in terminal mode.

Comment: @Daimrod it's also useful for pairing across a service like tmate

Comment: I keep a session log of every terminal session I run so that I leave an audit trail for myself. When emacs launches in a separate window, everything goes out-of-band. When I run emacs within the terminal, I'm more able to discern when I left it and what I did.

Comment: If I want to use a graphical editor or IDE, I'll do so. I use emacs when I want to edit plain text with NO magic.

Answer (score 256, accepted):

Emacs takes many launch options. The one that you are looking for is
`emacs -nw`. This will open Emacs inside the terminal disregarding the *DISPLAY* environment variable even if it is set.
The long form of this flag is `emacs --no-window-system`.

More information about Emacs launch options can be found in [the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Initial-Options.html#Initial-Options).

Answer (score 54):

Just type `emacs -nw`. This won't open an X window.

Answer (score 35):

In the spirit of providing functionality, go to your `.profile` or `.bashrc` file located at `/home/usr/` and at the bottom add the line:

```
alias enw='emacs -nw'
```

Now each time you open a terminal session you just type, for example, `enw` and you have the Emacs no-window option with three letters :).

Answer (score 13):

If you need to open Emacs without X:

```
emacs -nw
```

Comment: In the future, note that you need a newline for the code formatting to work properly. It got me the first couple times I used it too :)

Comment: Thanks, Tikhon! That's been pissing me off all day :P

Answer (score 5):

I didn't like the alias solution for my purposes. For one, it didn't work for setting `export EDITOR="emacs -nw"`.

But you can pass `--without-x` to configure and then just the regular old Emacs will always open in terminal.

```
curl http://gnu.mirrors.hoobly.com/emacs/emacs-25.3.tar.xz
tar -xvzf emacs-25.3.tar.xz && cd emacs-25.3
./configure --without-x
make && sudo make install
```

Comment: You could also just use a 1-line shell script, in your PATH

Answer (score 1):

```
emacs hello.c -nw
```

This is to open a *hello.c* file using Emacs inside the terminal.

Comment: This answer was already provided by the accepted answer two years prior.

Answer (score 0):

It can be useful also to add the option `--no-desktop` to avoid launching several buffers saved.

Answer (score 0):

Try `emacs —daemon` to have Emacs running in the background, and `emacsclient` to connect to the Emacs server.

It’s not much time overhead saved on modern systems, but it’s a lot better than running several instances of Emacs.